# how to resize the svg element using scale transform

Tags: svg, resize, scale

I have drawn the circle using svg. And binds the window resize event.
The actual svg circle radius is 200, svg width and height value is 500.  When resize the window it should be resize  using scaling.while increase the window size and decrease the window size. how to acheive this?

```
<body onresize="myFunction()">
<svg id='circle' height="500" width="500">
  <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="200" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
</body>

function myFunction(){
    var element = document.getElementById('circle');
    element.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(0.9)')   
}
```

Sample Link: https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/42891/

Comment: Check out this article [Making svg responsive](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/) by Sara Soueidan

Comment: bad idea.. you should recalculate the size

Comment: @Pirs yes that's the bad idea i am already recalculated. but i need another one more option so that i am asking this

Comment: try GSAP tweenlite, it should be really useful in your case

Comment: @Pirs that one is third party right?

Comment: What you mean when you say "third party" ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want an SVG to scale, it needs to have a viewBox.  Try:

```
viewBox="0 0 500 500"
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById('circle');
    element.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(0.9)')   
}
```

```html
<body onresize="myFunction()">
  <svg id='circle' width="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="200" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  </svg>
</body>
```

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/42894/)

But why are you trying to resize the SVG on window resize yourself?  Why not let the browser do it for you?

```html
<svg id='circle' width="50%" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="200" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/42893/)